# Call an API every 2 seconds for a period of one minute using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I am trying to make an api call (API1) every 2 seconds for a period of 1 minute. During this minute I need to exit the interval if condition is met and do another API call (API2). The problem that I am facing is if the API1 get into a pending state for more than 2 seconds, the second call of API1 will start and again if in pending state for 2 seconds the third call will happen ending up with quite few calls for same api all under pending state …. How can I stop the subsequent calls until the previous call is resolved?

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (triggerTheInterval) {
    startInterval()
    return () => clearInterval(id)
  }
}, [triggerTheInterval])

onClick = () => {
  makefirstcallforapi1();
}

//this is only to get the first call at first second - before the 2 seconds interval starts
const makefirstcallforapi1 = () => {

    setTimer(new Date().getTime());

    fetch(url).then(res => {
      if (conditionmet) {
        //do the API2 call
      } else {
        setTriggerTheInterval(true)
      }
    })

    startInterval = () => {
        id = setInterval(() => {
            fetch(url).then(res => {
                if ((new Date().getTime() - startTime > 60000 || condtionmet) {
                    //do something then exit the interval
                  }
                })
            }, 2000)
        }
```